# On Compilation The C++ Project throws Error C2228 which is not expected as the Control does not reaches the point at runtime

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, visual-studio-2017, c++17

Base Class Contains Public Function Bar(). 
foo() is a generic function which takes one parameter
When I pass Object of derived class it works fine but when I pass built in data type it must throw exception but it is showing compile time error C2228 In Visual Studio.

```
class Base
{
    public:
        void Bar();
};

class Derived:Base
{};

template<typename T>
void foo(T object)
{
    if(std::is_base_of<Base,T>::value == true)
        object.Bar();//Control does not reaches the point
    else
        throw "Invalid Parameter";
}
int main()
{
    Derived objDerived;
    foo(objDerived); //WORKS GOOD
    foo(2);//ERROR C2228
}
```

Comment: I want single function foo() to work differently for different datatypes

Comment: You probably don't want `throw` here. `static_assert` looks like a better fit.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is c++17 `if constexpr` instead. Otherwise, you will try to instantiate the branch which leads to the error. This is available in vs2017.

In c++11, you need two functions, not one, and use `enable_if` instead.